# Sort numbers followed by a letter with datatype varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to sort them in asc order for datatype as varchar, simple order by is not working

```
            A101
            A105
            A1201
            A234
            A1500
            A900
```

Result: I am expecting this result

```
            A101
            A105
            A234
            A900
            A1201
            A1500
```

Comment: Is the format ALWAYS a single Letter followed by a sequence of digits of variable length?

Comment: yes, the format always has a single letter and variable numbers

Comment: The simple sort is working very well - you are using a text type, so the sort uses text rules. `A124556` always comes before `A2`. If you wanted to use different parts of the field value differently you should use two separate fields. Applications that need to generate text values that still sort as numbers (eg invoice numbers, serial numbers) pad the numeric part with `0` so the string always has the same size, eg `A0001`, `A2340`

Comment: @SteveRichard if you want to quickly sort and search such values, don't use variable numbers. Pad them to a fixed size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order by the length and then the string:

```
order by len(col), col
```

Answer (score 4):

Since only one leading alpha character.

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable
 Order by left(SomeCol,1)
         ,try_convert(int,substring(SomeCol,2,10))
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol
A101
A105
A234
A900
A1201
A1500
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   select * from stack1 order by cast (substring(col1,2,100) as int) asc
```

output

```
A101
A105
A234
A900
A1201
A1500
```